# Что ломает защищенное соединение на сайте

Tags: http, веб-сервер, https

На что стоит обратить внимание или что необходимо проверить в данной ситуации.

Имеется сайт (их даже несколько) и у всех по разным причинам отваливается защищенное соединение. Т.е. сайт загружается по https все ок. но в какой то момент в консоле появляется ошибка, что такой то файл или такой то скрипт, а то и просто "загружена страница http://google.com по незащищенному соединению, таким образом вся ваша страница не незащищенном соединении".

Все скрипты и стили прописаны явно грузить по https. Что ломается, ничего не понимаю.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы сами ответили на свой вопрос, в какой-то момент происходит запрос по `http` изучайте внимательнее список запросов, может какие-то плагины делают запросы

Comment: Там же нарисовано на картинке :)) `google.ru` конечно! :))

Comment: Надо больше шпионской гугло бяки в код вставлять :) иногда и они лажают с кодом, что становятся видны выпуклые места :)